change event not triggerd bootstrap autocomplte
I am using bootstrap autocomplete ,
i ma facing issue regarding change event ,
when i select item from dropdown change event is not triggered
according to documentation
https://bootstrap-autocomplete.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#response-format-for-select
we can do that
here is my code snippet
$('.whatAutoComplete').autoComplete(
            {
                resolver: 'custom',
                events: {
                    search: function (qry, callback) {
                        
                        // let's do a custom ajax call
                        $.ajax(
                            searchwhatUrl,
                            {
                                data: { 'query': qry }
                            }
                        ).done(function (res) {
                            
                            if(res)
                            callback(res.data)
                           
                        });
                    },
                    change: function (evt, item) {
                        debugger;
                        // Handle the select event here
                        console.log("Selected value changed:", item);
                    }
                }
            }
        );

